# save a pdf and close it programatically

Tags: javascript, automation, acrobat

I am automataing a webbased application using Selenium Webdriver. 
A report is generated in PDF format is opened Acrobat reader. I have to save that PDF to a specific location and then close the pdf. So how can it be done thru automation. I tried searching on net and found this can be done using VB script but then need Adobe professional version for the same. Also the report that is generated doesnot have a specific title. That keeps changing.
Can this be done using javascript  ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to generate some PDF in JS, try http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf

It will return you an base64 string or an URI. Then you can redirect your visitor to the PDF (with this URI) or write down the base64 in a file.

Comment: jspdf is used to create a pdf, but in my case the pdf is generated and now need to save that pdf at a certain location in the system.